# How can I test the performance of each memory in a Centos7 HPC computing node remotely accessed?

Tags: linux, memory, centos7, cpu-architecture, hpc

I am using an HPC Cluster that is accessed remotely and has several computing nodes. The operating system is Centos7.
However, it was confirmed that the performance of some computing nodes was poor, and the cause was confirmed that one of the RAMs in the computing node had poor performance.

There are 12 RAMs in one computing node. Is there a way to test the performance of each memory?
It would be appreciated if you could recommend a script provided by a place like intel.

Unfortunately, the memtest86+ program cannot be installed on my cluster.

I tried using the mlc script provided by intel, but it was difficult to check the performance of each memory.
(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/intelr-memory-latency-checker.html)

I want to check the performance of each RAM. Please help me

Comment: If you have physical access, take out half the memory modules on that node and see if bandwidth / latency are still bad.  If not, the problem was either one of the DIMMs you removed, or it was a loose connection or something in one of the sockets, or a problem with how that motherboard handles all 12 DIMMs being active.

Comment: If you're getting ECC errors, the kernel's error logs should hopefully show which DIMM had the memory that needed correction or that failed.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/edac-util might be relevant if the kernel doesn't log it as text on its own.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/edac.html